# How do I output to website instead of console for debugging in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

Well the title explains pretty much everything.
I want to use something like

```
p something
```

And be able to see the output in the website, just for the sake of debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're coming from PHP, because this is a very PHP-esque thing to want to do. Standard output isn't sent to the browser in Rails, something PHP developers take for granted.

If you want to see something in browser, you need to render it.

From a view you can use the `debug` helper to "vardump" a value:

```
<%= debug something %>
```

From a controller you can quickly see the value of a variable using `render :inline => p(something)` or `render :inline => something.inspect`. Make sure you `return` afterwards or otherwise prevent yourself from reaching a second `render` call.

You should get used `tail`ing your log files, and making use of the [Rails logger](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Logger.html#M000167).

Comment: Indeed I come from PHP :P
I read that solution somewhere else, but I was searching for something more "global"
Thanks ^^

Comment: If I could up-vote just the last paragraph, I would. Zequez, definitely learn to love the log!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest piggy-backing off of the Rails **flash** maps.  In a controller, use the following:

```
 flash[:log] = "<li>Log: #{log_info}</li>"
```

Then in your view (possibly in your layout) use:

```
 <% if !flash[:log].blank? && RAILS_ENV != 'production' %>
   <ul class="logs">
     <%= flash[:log] %>
   </ul>
 <% end %>
```

That should put it out on your page!

You can also put the following in **ApplicationController**

```
 def log(msg)
   flash[:log] ||= ""
   flash[:log] += "<li>#{Time.new.to_s} - #{msg}</li>"
 end
```

Then simply call from any controller:

```
 log("Hi stackoverflow.")
```

Or from any view:

```
 @controller.log("Hi there, you!")
```

Comment: Woah! Thanks! Perfect solution! ^^

Comment: Good solution! One note: `flash[:log] ||= ""` is more idiomatic and shorter approach than the original `flash[:log] = "" if flash[:log].nil?`. Also, there is a typo in the `log` method: see `<li>...</p>` - probably this is not correct.